# Android - Manage the notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

I wante to create some notifications to user.
Ex : when a new comment, when someone ask question,...
I know how to create notification, but i don't know how can i do for send a notification just one time.
Example : notification is send to user because he has a new comment. He click on the notification for start application and watch the comment. But now,  how can i avoid that it receives twice the same notification ?
It is recommended to store it in a database, in "notification" table or it exist a system for manage this ?

I'm sorry for the very bad English.

Comment: if you are using same notification id. the previous notification will be replaced with new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking if the notification is already displayed.

```
private boolean isNotificationVisible() {
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent test = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, MY_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
return test != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Google Cloud Messaging?

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

If you've already implemented this, and you're receiving the same notification twice, it might have something to do with how you are building the Notification. If the link above doesn't help, can you post more information, and possibly the code?